# use jQuery Ajax with Spring mvc but can't call controller functions

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I try to use jQuery Ajax to partially update html contents. I checked out how ajax cooperate with spring mvc and I follow some tutorials.
but I can't get the desired result. It seems like the controller doesn't even be called.
how to fix this bug?
thanks in advance.

jsp file

```
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>管理员面板</title>
<spring:url value="/resources/css/minputs.css" var = "minputscss"/>
<link  rel="stylesheet" href = "${minputscss}" type ="text/css"/>
<script src="<c:url value='/resources/js/button.js'/>" type="text/javascript" />
<script src="<c:url value='/resources/js/jquery-1.6.4.min.js' />" type="text/javascript"/>
<script src="<c:url value ='/resources/js/commen.js'/>" type="text/javascript"/>
</head>
<body style="background:#202020">
<div id="mainContent" style="width:80%;float:right">

<table>
<tr>title:<input id="title"/></tr>
<tr>content:<input id="content"/><tr>   
<tr>
<button type="button" id="submitButton" onclick="submitButton();" value="submit">submit</button>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
<script>

function submitButton() {
    var title = document.getElementById("title").value;
    var content = document.getElementById("content").value;
    alert("test"+title+content);

    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        contentType : "application/json",
        url : "submitArticle",
        data :{
            title:title,
            content:content
            },
        dataType : 'json',
        timeout : 100000,
        success : function(data) {
            console.log("SUCCESS: ", data);
            alert(data);
        },
        error : function(e) {
            console.log("ERROR: ", e);
            alert(e);
        },
        done : function(e) {
            console.log("DONE");
            alert("done");
        }
    });
}



</script>
```

controller

```
package com.plainart.controller;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

import com.plainart.entity.Article;
import com.plainart.service.UploadService;

@Controller
public class EditorController {


    @Autowired
    private UploadService uploadService;

    @RequestMapping(value ="/submitArticle", method =RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody
    String submitArticle(@RequestBody Article art,HttpServletRequest request){
        Date now = new Date();
        System.out.println("receive");
        uploadService.uploadArticleInfo(art);
        String path = uploadService.uploadArticle(art.getTitle()+art.getId(), art.getContent());
        return path;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please add an example of the json that you're sending and the error that you're getting.

Comment: Post the code of `Article`

Comment: thanks to all of you. The major problem is I didn't link the jQuery properly,and also write the controller with a wrong @RequestBody annotation.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `dataType`:

```
dataType : 'text',
```

As you are not producing any json from the method.

And when you use `@RequestBody` annotation then it is a must to send in the request:

```
 data :{
    art: "someArt"
    title:title,
    content:content
 },
```

Comment: take a look at the console and see if you get some error. or you could tell us what is the actual behavior of it.

Comment: Actually I intended to map the parameters into a Entity Artist, and I just copy the tutorial structure and I don't know wether it fits my situation.

Comment: no errors after clicking. my ajax function doesn't even reach my controller.

Comment: Did you try to debug in the source (Developers Tools/F12)? Also what was the request made, the url?